# ng-messages aren't displayed in custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I created a custom directive which is used to access the id of the form, to display messages if same validation failed.

directive Code

```
<div> 
    <md-input-container>
      <label class="inputLabel" translate>amount</label>
      <input ng-model="order.amount" name="amount" type="text" required
             max="availableAmount"
             ng-disabled="disabled" ng-currency flex/>
      <ng-messages flex for="dataForm.amount.$error" ng-if="dataForm.amount.$dirty">
        <ng-message when="max">max reached</ng-message>
      </ng-messages>
    </md-input-container>
</div>
```

usage:

```
<form id="dataForm">
   <custom-directive></custom-directive>
</form>
```

It seems like I can not access the form. Or angularmessage can not handle the different scoping.

Has anyone the same problem or an idea?
Thank you

fyi.: I have found the following post, but I didn't think that i have the same problem as that guy. 
[angularjs ngMessages inside directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33429542/angularjs-ngmessages-inside-directive)

I use Angular 1.4.8;message 1.4.8 and angular material 1.0.4

Comment: Does you directive have isolated scope? the "dataForm" object is in the outer scope of the directive, so if you have an isolated scope (and you should), it is not accessible. Angular supports multiple forms, so you can wrap the md-input-container in your directive with a form of it's own.

Comment: Yes, I use an isolated scope.
Thank you, that was the solution. 
I wrapped the directive template with <ng-form> and everything was fine.

Comment: Excellent, I've posted this an answer as well, to help someone that will search it in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If directive have an isolated scope, than it will not be able to access the form controller object of the ng-form directive.

Angular enables multiple canonical forms, so you can simply wrap your input inside of your directive with a form / ng-form.